# Ajax on each dynamically generated table rows

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a table whose rows are dynamically generated using jQyery. Each row will have a dropdown and a textbox. The text box will be auto populated based on dropdown selection on each row. My codes work for the first row but no for the newly added rows. Here are my codes..

Jquery

```
$('select[name^="itemName"]').on('change',function(){
        var itemName = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'retrieve_item.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{itemName:itemName},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                var itemRate = data.ItemRate;
                $(this).closest('tr').find($('input[name^="rate"]').val(itemRate));
            },
            error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `$(this)` in success callback, which does't refer the element which invoked the event.

You need to store the reference of `$(this)` and use it in the success callback.

Use

```
$('select[name^="itemName"]').on('change',function(){
    var _this = $(this); //Store the reference in a variable

    var itemName = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        success:function(data){
            //Use the reference here
            _this.closest('tr').find('input[name^="rate"]').val(data.ItemRate));
        },
    });
});
```

Also you have syntax error, `.find($('input[name^="rate"]')` should be `.find('input[name^="rate"]')`. removed `$(` from selector.

Also as per comment *Newly added rows are not getting populated.*:

As you are creating controls dynamically. You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

*Use*

```
$(document).on('click', 'select[name^="itemName"]', function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container for better performance.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: No Satpal. Your code is not working either. Only the first row is getting populated. Newly added rows are not getting populated.

Comment: @IndraGotamey, Try with `$(document).on('click', 'select[name^="itemName"]', function(){` instead of `$('select[name^="itemName"]').on('change',function(){` if it works I will provide explanation

Comment: @SatPan. Yes it works using $(document). I never thought It would be so simple. Could you please explain me why it works with $(document) and not with normal selector? Thank you

Comment: @Satpal- I am sorry I misspelled your name. But thank you so much. I have been wrecking my head for so long to solve this.

Comment: Do I have to use delegation if I have to calculate the sum total of values in these dynamically generated textboxes?? Thanks in advance..